# Can we use regular expression in solr elevate.xml configuration

Tags: solr

We are using below elevate.xml to get desired results in order in solr configuration.

```
<query text="hotels">
<doc id="14421"/>
</query>
<query text="Hotels">
<doc id="14421"/>
</query>
```

Now, we got requirement with list of keywords(> 50 words). If I hardcode all these in elevate.xml I can fulfill my requirement. I want to know is there any better approach for this like configuring reqgural expression or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

you could try two options:

1. putting the elevated ids in the request at query time, see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component)
2. this guy created a plugin to generate the elevate.xml from a db, which you maintain, see in [here](https://medium.com/@kaismh/automated-solution-for-query-elevation-using-solr-a15ce88b2762)

Comment: Thanks persimmonium. I have tried but not matched with my requirement.